# Insert into Table from Query with CTE and Pivot

Tags: insert, pivot, ssms, common-table-expression

I have query which return results in a pivot format I want to insert this into a SQL table. 
Ultimately I will create a agent job which runs 10PM every night and inserts records into the table. 
I can find examples where people have used CTE and then results of the CTE into the table but mine us more complex as I have pivoted the results.

Can anyone please help me?

below is the script

```
WITH CTE as 

(SELECT

org.StudioMain,
BUD.ForecastProbability as 'Prob%',
(BUD.ForecastProbability*BUD.AmountOrgCurrency) as ForecastAmountOrg,
(BUD.ForecastProbability*CASE
WHEN org.EntityCode = 'WAU' AND org.Studio = 'Sydney' THEN 
BUD.AmountOrgCurrency/NULLIF(bud.ForecastCurrencyToNZDfx,0)
WHEN org.EntityCode = 'WAU' AND org.Studio = 'Melbourne' THEN 
BUD.AmountOrgCurrency/NULLIF(bud.ForecastCurrencyToNZDfx,0)
else BUD.AmountOrgCurrency
end) as ForecastAmountNZD


FROM EDWH.dbo.FactBudgets AS BUD
INNER JOIN [ODS].[dbo].[PeriodTriggerMain] as T ON BUD.BudgetName = T.BudgetName
LEFT JOIN EDWH.dbo.DimOrg as Org on BUD.DimOrgKey = org.DimOrgKey
LEFT JOIN ODS.dbo.DimFinPeriodDate as Period on BUD.DimFinPeriodDateKey = Period.DimFinPeriodDateKey
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT WBS1, ProjectName, Principal, Sector FROM EDWH.dbo.DimProject where WBS2 = 
'') as PRN ON BUD.WBS1 = PRN.WBS1


WHERE 
CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(day,0,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(month, 3, 
datefromparts(left(BUD.FinPeriod, 4)-1, right(BUD.FinPeriod, 2), 1))),0)),120) BETWEEN
CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(day,0,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(month, 3, 
datefromparts(left(T.ForecastPeriod, 4)-1, right(T.ForecastPeriod, 2), 1))),0)),120) AND
CONVERT(varchar(10),dateadd(day,0,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,dateadd(month, 14, 
datefromparts(left(T.ForecastPeriod, 4)-1, right(T.ForecastPeriod, 2), 1))),0)),120) 
)
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
StudioMain,
Currency = 'NZD',
SUM(ForecastAmountNZD) as AmountNZD,
getdate() as Timestamp

FROM CTE as f

GROUP BY
StudioMain
) as NZD

PIVOT(
SUM(AmountNZD)
FOR [StudioMain] IN  
([AKL], [CHC], [MEL], [QNT], [SYD], [WEL], [WMT])
)
AS Pivot_Table

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
StudioMain,
Currency = 'ORG',
SUM(ForecastAmountOrg) as AmountOrg,
getdate() as Timestamp

FROM CTE as f

GROUP BY
StudioMain
) as Org

PIVOT(
SUM(AmountOrg)
FOR [StudioMain] IN
([AKL], [CHC], [MEL], [QNT], [SYD], [WEL], [WMT])
)
AS Pivot_Table
```

[image]

I want to insert the results into a table;
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a view of the CTE query and then point the agent job to the view.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand,

1. You need to insert execution results of PIVOT based SQL Query into a Table. So we will create one table with below columns,
2. Currency, TimeStamp, AKL, CHC, MEL, QNT, SYD, WEL, WMT
3. Then you will create one SQL Agent Job where you will pass your SQL Query to fetch the data.
4. In the Source you need to mention the database details of the table used in your query.
5. In the Destination you need to mention the new table which you are going to create
6. Schedule this Job to run every day at 10PM
7. Check the Job by doing Start Job at Step to see if that getting succeeded and data is getting inserted into you new table.

Even though, the query has PIVOT function, it will be a simple SQL Agent JOB to insert desired data into destination table.

Comment: One way around is I add this query as a view then in sql agent job i call the view. This is working currently.

Comment: That's also a good idea. If that works for you.. please post is an answer so that others also know the working way..